# after all stack overflow solution still cant fb login on my local host server

Tags: php, fbconnect, fbloginview

The most voted  answer to change host file I have change into my website name which is not live domain but on my local domain

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost/great
```

after this I made test application also fbdevelopers and change domain into localhost

[image]

and after this I have comment all the fb login code of running app on live server and integrate fb login code

```
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    alert("yes");
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);


    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else {

      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    }
  }


  function checkLoginState() {
    alert("here");
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    alert("ghhh");
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1726174127690844',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.10'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };


  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };


  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
```

and the button of fb login

```
<fb:login-button 
  scope="public_profile,email"
  onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>
  <div id="status">
</div>
```

but still getting an error

```
Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domain
```

please genius where I am wrong do correct me please kindly give me your expert advice

Comment: try using "127.0.0.1       mytestdomain.com" and use mytestdomain.com on fb app domain

Comment: you want me to edit host file and  change great  to great.com

Comment: yes you should add another line in your host file "127.0.0.1       great.com" and your site will be available on great.com/great ( if its in great folder )

Comment: sir i have add line like you said  and have undo the remaining lines of 127.0.0.1  but still cant see my site on browser by hitting url http://localhost/great.com/great

Comment: sorry in advance if i am acting dump

Answer (score 0):

You should add new temporary domain or use your live site domain while you are developing it on your localhost for your localhost like

```
127.0.0.1       yoursitedomain.com
```

and use yoursitedomain.com as fb app domain
this way fb will not reject the domain and you will be able to implement it from your localhost too

Comment: but sir on fb app domain they are not accepting this url

Comment: you can try with your live site domain then, this is an example of how you should resolve the issue.

Comment: sir i dont  have access thats the reason i want to run on fb login on my local server  and  on live site it is running perfectly

Comment: sir is that necessary to have temporary domain as i dont have it fblogin cant work on local host purely

Comment: you can skip it

Comment: then sir what i am missing  why fb login is not connecting in localhost